# Child commands in popen telnet

Tags: c++, session, fork, telnet, popen

I am trying to establish a local telnet session in C++ and send commands/receive data. Right now I have:

```
const char *cmd = "telnet 127.0.0.1 2006";
char buffer[256];

FILE *pipe = popen(cmd, "rw");   
//if( !pipe ) { perror("popen"); exit(-1); }

while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pipe) != NULL &&   
      !feof(pipe) )
{
    if( ferror(pipe) ) { perror("fgets"); break; }

    /* Here you do whatever you want with the data. */
    printf("%s", buffer);
}

pclose(pipe);
```

Which is opening the telnet connection. I need to send a command like: "/neighbors" and then receive the data it would return. Ideally, the session would remain open and I would re-query "/neighbors" every 20 seconds or so.

I think I need to create a child process with fork(), but I am very new to this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `telnet` seems like a rather roundabout way to do this. Have you considered using regular sockets to talk to the remote process? For example, try this [guide to socket programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Comment: A thousand times this.  Starting with telnet and popen and now about to use fork, the OP is going to end up with a dozen problems.

Comment: I have to use telnet because I am running a terminal application I didn't create that is outputting data only to telnet that I need to pull into C++

Comment: The `telnet` program is just a convenient way of connecting a terminal session to a remote socket server. All `telnet` does is use regular socket API functions to make the connection to the server. The server doesn't know what program is making the connection. Therefore, you can use socket API functions to make your *own* connection to the server.